# 2way cache associative ? how many bytes do I read from memory?

Tags: c, caching, memory, memory-management

Given the code :

```
void transpose2(array dst,array src)
{
  int i,j;
  for ( i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for ( j=0; j<4; j++) {
     dst[i][j] = src[j][i];
    }
  }
}
```

Assumptions :

- int is 4 bytes
- `src` array starts at address `0` , `dst` starts at address `64`
- the size of the cache is `32` bytes , at the beginning the cache is empty

Assuming that I have a cache with size of `32` bytes , under write through ,write allocate & LRU , using 2way set associative method , where each block is `8` bytes :

When I read from the memory , how many bytes do I take each iteration from the memory ?

is it `4` or `8` ?

What I'm quite sure about is that the cache has 4 cells , or rows , and each row has 8 bytes .Is this correct ?

What is a little confusing is the **2way** part , I think that each way has `4` bytes , right ? please correct me if I'm wrong ...

Then when I "take" a block from the memory , I just don't exactly understand how many bytes !!?

Thanks in advance

Ron

Comment: Is this homework or just self-learning/curiosity? 32-byte caches don't exist.

Comment: @Mysticial: This is no homework , this is an exercise before an exam that I'm going to have in the following week .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cache way (aka its associativity) does not affect the amount of data that's transferred when a transfer occurs; the block size **is** the block size.

Associativity is simply a measure how many possible locations there are in the cache that a given block from memory could be stored.  So:

- For a direct-mapped cache (associativity=1), memory address `xyz` will *always* map to the same cache location.
- For a two-way cache, `xyz` could map to either of two cache locations.
- For a fully-associative cache, `xyz` could map to *anywhere* in cache.

I'm really not saying anything here which isn't already explained at e.g. Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Associativity.

Comment: So what you're saying is that each iteration , I take 8 bytes ?

Comment: @ron: It depends on how many hits and misses there are.  There will either be 8, 16 or 24 bytes transferred.

Comment: Each cell of the cache , has 2 ways ? and each way has 4 bytes ? thanks .

Comment: @ron: The number of ways is a property of the cache itself, not of each block.  Blocks are not sub-divided into ways.

Comment: Excuse me , Oli , but I lost you . I'm just trying to picture the look of the cache . As I see it at the moment , the cache has 4 cells , each cells has 8 bytes (therefore total of 32 bytes) , and each cell of the cache can have at the maximum , two locations , where each location is 4 bytes . Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ron: No.  The number of ways does not affect the number of locations.  If you have a 32-byte cache, and a block size of 8, then there are 4 blocks.  Any given memory address can map to 2 different blocks.

Answer (score 0):

When the CPU references (load or store) a word from a block that is not in the cache, that block is demanded to memory. So, with the parameters supplied, every cache miss involves a 8 byte transfer from memory to cache.

Related to the terminology, your cache has 4 entries, containers or cache lines (32 bytes / 8 bytes/block). As it is 2-way associative, there are 2 sets of 2 entries. Blocks with even addreses map to set 0, while blocks with odd addresses map to set 1.

Block addresses are obtained by shifting the word address log2(block_size) bits (3 bits in your cache).
For example:

- address 64 belongs to block 8
- address 72 belongs to block 9